# Findbugs - "close() invoked on a value that is always null"

Tags: java, findbugs, sonarqube

I have this block of code

```
private void doSomething(Properties properties) throws XXException 
{
    PersistenceManager pm = null;        

    try {
        pm = new PersistenceManager(distributedDatabase, "PeriodHelper: insertPeriod");

        try {
            pm.create(Tables.MY_TABLE);
        } catch (ObjectAlreadyExistsException e) {
            logger.warn("Could not create table! - "+e.getMessage(), e);
            return;
        }

        pm.commit();
        return;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new XXException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally {
        if (pm != null) 
            pm.close();
    }
}
```

that findbugs/sonar is reporting is afflicted by

```
Correctness - close() invoked on a value that is always null
close() is being invoked on a value that is always null. If this statement 
is executed, a null pointer exception will occur. But the big risk here you
never close something that should be closed.
Key:    NP_CLOSING_NULL
```

but if you look at the code, the pm object when the close() method is called will always be not null. Can anyone explain why findbugs is getting this wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code before and inside the finally clause?

Comment: You have over 30 questions without an accepted answer.  Perhaps you could review old question to see there are acceptable answers.

Comment: Your error is in line 42 of your code.  If it isn't obvious **post the code** and we can point it out to you.

Comment: updated the code example and reviewed and accepted some old answers

Comment: Any chance that this code is being modified with aspects or the like? I'd really have to see the byte code that was generated for this method to tell you if it really was a problem or not... or whether it was just Findbugs having a bad hair day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Either* Findbugs is simply wrong (wouldn't be the first time) **or** it knows that `pm` can't be non-null here (in which case it would kind-of report the wrong error, it *should* say "dead code" or "condition is always false").

Answer (score -1):

Do you try to enclose the if statment using braces?

```
if (pm!=null) {pm.close()};
```

Comment: I wasn't telling this just to say something. Sometimes, Netbeans complains about something until I add brace. And I don't talk about the "If statement should use braces" advices…